# Understanding bind_front when used with classes

Tags: c++

[New to CPP bind] I understand bind_front when it is used on context of non class functions. Can someone help me understand the following piece of code, which uses bind_front in context of class ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

class foo
{
    void bar() { std::cout << "foo::bar" << '\n'; }
};

int main()
{
    Foo my_foo;
    auto f1 = std::bind_front(&foo::bar, &my_foo);

    f1();
}
```

Essentially whats binding a function to a class pointer does ?

Comment: FWIW, you should really use a lambdas instead of `bind`.  They can do everything bind can, and more.

Comment: You say `bind_front`, but the code uses the regular `bind`?

Comment: Edited to use bind_front :)

Answer (score 0):

As [documented](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind_front), calling the function-call operator of the object returned by`std::bind_front` function is equivalent to calling [`std::invoke`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke).

And `std::invoke` is specified to take the first function argument (i.e. `&my_foo` in your example) and use as the object to call the member function on.

So your call

```
f1();
```

is equivalent to

```
std::invoke(&foo::bar, &my_foo);
```

which is equivalent to

```
(&my_foo)->bar();
```

Comment: I see, Does that mean bar can still use any member variables of the class ?

Comment: @danishsodhi Yes, it's a normal member function like any other. As long as it's called on a valid object it can do anything any other member function does.